# mixed partials for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Can someone please help me. 
if $ u  = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} , v = -\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}$

and $ \phi = (2x)^{\alpha} f(\eta)$  where $ \eta = (2x)^{\beta}y$

I need,

to work out $ \phi_{y}\phi_{xy}-\phi_{x}\phi_{yy} = 2m(2x)^{2m-1} + \phi_{yyy}$

now I can work out that

$ \phi_{y} = (2x)^{\alpha+\beta} $  but not sure if this correct? Also I dont know to work out $ \phi_{xy} $

Answer (score 0):

Use the chain rule.
$$
\phi_x=2\,\alpha\,(2\,x)^{\alpha-1}f(\eta)+(2\,x)^\alpha\,f'(\eta)\,\eta_x=2\,\alpha\,(2\,x)^{\alpha-1}f(\eta)+2\,\beta\,(2\,x)^{\beta-1}y\,f'(\eta)
$$
$$
\phi_y=(2\,x)^\alpha\,f'(\eta)\,\eta_y=(2\,x)^{\alpha+\beta}f'(\eta)
$$
Can you go on?

Comment: I dont know how to work out the mixed partial $\phi_{xy} $

Comment: Just take the derivative with respect to $y$ of $\phi_x$:$$\phi_{xy}=2\,\alpha\,(2\,x)^{\alpha-1}f'(\eta)\,\eta_y+2\,\beta\,(2\,x)^{\beta-1}\,f'(\eta)+2\,\beta\,(2\,x)^{\beta-1}\,y\,f''(\eta)\,\eta_y$$